# Add CSS Class attribute to Standard Umbraco Image Editor

Tags: css, umbraco7, image-editor

I am new to Umbraco, and just discovered that the Image editor (the one that is included in selectable editors for content rows) does not provide a way to enter a CSS class. This is surprising, considering that it is pretty standard these days to use Bootstrap classes to style images (img-responsive, for example). NOTE: I had planned to add screen shots of this; however, I've been given a message that I cannot do this until I earn 10 something-or-other-points. THIS NOT HELPFUL TO NEW MEMBERS!

While I understand that I can set a class within the Umbraco UI on the containing column div, this is not ideal. I also understand that I could use the Rich Text Editor, but this seems to be overkill for a column that is intended to contain images only.

What I would like to do is modify the existing editor to allow users to enter CSS classes, but I cannot find it.

Has anyone made this modification to your own implementation of Umbraco, and if so, could you guide me to how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

The image picker just stores the id of the image, it's up to you how you render it, if the classes are the same for all of the images in the column, you can just assign the class in the view/partial that renders the images.

If you want to have different classes for each image, rather than modifying the built in image picker, best practice is to create a new property editor. There is a tutorial on this here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/tutorials/Creating-a-Property-Editor/. Modifying the built in one will cause you problems if you ever upgrade Umbraco (your changes will be overwritten). But a custom property editor will be unaffected, and you can also use it on other Umbraco sites that you build!